# How to get the CSS left, top, width, height from coords?

Tags: html, css, mapping, mozilla

Using image map tool i have made 5 rectangle boxes, but instead of rectangle boxes they need to become actually `<input type=text style="position:absolute; left: ??px; top: ??px; width:??px; height:??px;" />` with correct left, top, width, height

[image]

Image map tool:

https://developer.cdn.mozilla.net/media/uploads/demos/s/u/summerstyle/365ccfd644f2b008c33f0046d2ba1a8f/summer-html-image-ma_1355318513_demo_package/index.html

code generated:

```
<img src="a.png" alt="" usemap="#map" />
<map name="map">
    <area shape="rect" coords="961, 542, 1269, 611" />
    <area shape="rect" coords="245, 300, 606, 340" />
    <area shape="rect" coords="245, 247, 605, 286" />
    <area shape="rect" coords="245, 194, 605, 234" />
    <area shape="rect" coords="246, 142, 606, 183" />
</map>
```

How do i convert the generated coords into css left, top, width, height?

Comment: you need some javascript

Comment: Please see the screen shot. image map tool only creates <area with coords, i need to manually convert those coords into left,top,width,height. how?

Comment: I believe that `coords` defines (left-top-x, left-top-y, right-bottom-x, right-bottom-y), so `left = left-top-x`, `top = left-top-y`, `width = right-bottom-x - left-top-x`,  `height = right-bottom-y - left-top-y`

Comment: @LotAbout: can your formula be updated in that application as contribution so that there is a button which can give this auto calculation? see: https://github.com/summerstyle/summer/issues/7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the [`<area>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/area) coords `x1`, `y1`, `x2`, `y2`.

These are relative to the top left corner of your image which we can assume will also be the top left corner of a `<div>` which will contain your `<input>` elements `x1` is `left` and `y1` is `top`.

The `<div>` should have `position: relative` and the `<input>` have `position: absolute`.

Alternatively since you appear to need them right aligned you can ignore the `x1` value and just set `right: 0` and then you just need the `top` values.

This does seem a strange approach to layout rather than using the normal flow.